# Rejecting Angular $http promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to reject an `$http` promise call in the success/then function. I can see 2 options: 1) thrown an error - this garbages up the console and 2) use separate defer call and reject that. Is there a cleaner/more concise way? I have a feeling I am overlooking something obvious.

Error:

```
return $http.get(url}.then(function(r) {
  throw new Error('Booh');
});
```

With $q:

```
var deferred = $q.defer();
$http.get(url}.then(function(r) {
   deferred.reject("Booh");
});
return deferred.promise;
```

Comment: This sounds like a job for [Interceptors](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#interceptors)

Comment: why would you want to reject from success handler in the first place?

Comment: @code-jaff - the definition of success for $http is not the same as for myself. Sometimes it successfully returns invalid data so I wish for the calling function to have the "correct" response.

Comment: If you can modify the response from the server, I'd prefer to return responses with appropriate http response codes, therefore will be treated as errors in client side.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
function myfunction()
{
    return $http.post('url')
        .then(function(response){
            // check success-property of returned data
            if(response.data === 'Something you dont want')
                return $q.reject('some error occured');
            else{
                return $q.resolve(response.data);
            }
        })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As $http is a modified promise do something like :

```
var deferred = $q.defer();

$http.get(url).success(function(r) {
   if(r != 'your criteria')
       deferred.reject("Booh");
   else
       deferred.resolve("Baah");
}).error(function(){
   deferred.reject("Beeh");
});

return deferred.promise
```

Comment: I can't do the 2nd because I need to reject a successful result (the result is successful but didn't meet my criteria). I am currently using the 1st solution but hoping for a more concise way

Answer (score 0):

You can use de reject method of the $q service to immetiately forward to the next error section, something like:

```
var deferred = $q.defer();

$http.get(url}.success(function(r) {
     deferred.reject();
}).error(function(){
   // do something
});
```

When success q.reject will forward to the error and do something...